# In which site of StackExchange should I ask questions about computer networks?

Tags: support

I'm dealing with some basic network configuration problems while using cisco's packet tracer software to improve my knowledge about networking, and I can't figure out where to get the answer for them.

Some questions may be software specific and most may not, because this software simulates a real environment, and many questions can be applied to a real life scenario as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless something changed since I was a NE moderator, questions about packet tracer are on topic since PT is a tool used by network engineers.

That said, you're probably much better off using Cisco Virl instead of PT.  PT is so quirky, it often gets in the way more than it helps.  Virl runs a real IOS image instead of simulating IOS like PT does.

Read more about the options here...
http://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2016/09/virl-vs-gns3-vs-packet-tracer-which-one/

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer may be "none", since Stack Exchange sites are for the most part not learning sites.

Most question you could have about networking basics are already answered somewhere on the Internet. So the first thing to do is to perform some researches including (but not limited to) the Stak Exchange network

Each S.E. site has its own policy regarding which type of question can be asked, so you'll to check the help center of some of them to determine if your question fit.

Concerning this S.E. site , I.E. network engineering, educational questions are explicitly off-topic. (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

However when the questions are specific enough, properly formatted, show some research and are relevant to the field, they often get an answer.

Edit: you can also try the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) where you may find help about questions that are otherwise out of topic on the site itself.

Comment: SE is the last place I go to in search for answers when everything else has failed me, and it never failed me till now. If I'm asking is because I couldn't find the answer anywhere else. Btw, it's curious how you don't consider solving doubts as part of a learning process.

Comment: Note that I tried to reflect here the position decided by the community. It doesn't necessarily reflect my own feeling. You may also find help in the chat were you are free to ask questions that are off-topic on the site. But I don't get it with "you don't consider solving doubts as part of a learning proces" since, once again, this is NOT a learning site.